# Remove Persistent Notification with Alarm Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

I have an application which shows an alarm at the specific time every day, I set an AlarmManager to do this. Now I want that my persistent notification cancels after one hour. I know I should make another AlarmManager and cancel the first one, but how can I specify that it must be canceled after "An Hour"?

```
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,01);
    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100
    ,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingintent);
```

and this is my receiver:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context
    .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context, SurveyActivity.class);
    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent .getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notiflogo)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm")
            .setContentText("This is Alarm")
            .setTicker("Hello")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    builder.setOngoing(true); 
    notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you know that you can cancel your notification by its id (you set it to 100 in ur code).  To implement expiration, you just need to set another one-time (non-repeating) alarm that cancels your notification. You set that alarm right after you show your notifcation like this:

```
notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent=new Intent(context,NotificationCancelReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("notification_id", 100);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, 0);

    // Here's two way to fire a one-time (non-repeating) alarm in one hour
    // One way: alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,  System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent); 
    // Another way:
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
    // If you want to wake up the system with this alarm use ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP not ELAPSED_REALTIME
```

And here's your NotificationCancelReceiver that cancels notification:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("notification_id", -1);
        if (id != -1) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(id);
        }
}
```

And make sure that you added reciever in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationCancelReceiver">
</receiver>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is exactly what I wanted but I don't know why it doesn't work. Firstly, I think in this line the third argument must be intent, am I right? `PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, pi, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
`  and then I set exactly my alarm for one minute later after my  specific time for testing `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        01 * 60 * 1000, pi);` but notification is still there. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please, have a look. 
Don't forget to add reciever into AndroidManifest. And I listed two way to set alarm, try each of them. Also I deleted setting action to intent and checking for it inside onRecieve.
Yes, the thrid argument of PendingIntent.getBroadcast is intent - I made a mistake in hurry.